# A case to avoid a linear mixed effect model

Tags: r, bioinformatics, generalized-linear-model

This is a simplified explanation of my experiment, for those not familiar with single cell RNA seq.
24 small chunks of brain were taken from 12 diseased people and 12 normal people.  Gene expression was measured in each individual cell from the 24 samples. each sample contains about 1000 cells.  I want to see if gene expression and disease status are associated. We all know that different people have different genetics, and so gene expression is confounded from person to person. As such, I am modeling gene expression using sample_ID as a random intercept.

```
gene_expression ~ diagnosis + age + sex + pmi + n_genes + 
                  (1 | sample_id)
```

age: self explanatory

sex: self explanatory

pmi: post mortem index. a confounding variable to gene expression.

n_genes: the number of genes expressed within the cell.

diagnosis is my variable of interest ... I want to see if diagnosis is associated with gene expression.

I think using sample ID as a random intercept is not useful.  Within a sample, all the cells have the same diagnosis, age, sex, and pmi. within a sample , the only thing that varies cell to cell is n_genes.

If I plot `gene_expression ~ age`, the data looks like this:

[image]

Fitting a line to this data, then adding a random intercept, the line will just be shifted up/down until it hits the mean of each sample.

[image]

In the above example, it would be just as good to model

```
gene_expression ~ (1 | sample_id)
```

I gather that the main reason to avoid mixed effect models is not having enough factor levels in the random effect.  Based on this reasoning, it was suggested that I do not have enough samples.  However, I think that even if I had infinite samples, this problem would still persist.

It seems that if the other confounding variables do not vary within a factor level, that they become useless when the random effect is added.  They are essentially an intercept, because Beta*age, Beta*sex Beta*pmi is the same for all cells in a sample.

I believe that because diagnosis, age, sex, and PMI do not vary within a sample, that adding sample_ID as a random intercept is not useful.

The strangest thing, however, is that when the likelihood ratio test is performed on diagnosis, some values are showing up as significant.  I would expect no significant results from diagnosis, because the model is just doing this:

```
gene_expression ~ n_genes + (1 | sample_ID)
```

Comment: What is the goal here? What are you trying to identify with `gene_expression ~` ? I ask this because in single cell RNA if I remember correctly one can measure DGE (differential gene expression) across different cell types. It is true that the sample ID is a random effect. I am unsure if Seurat (3.X) allows adjustment of covariates before the DGE analysis. It Is true if you're identifying gene expression variability within same individual the covariates needn't be used. I hope I am not wrong.

Comment: Where do the identities of the genes whose expression levels are being measured come into your analysis?